# Why does S3EventSourceV2 not work the same as S3EventSource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, triggers

I had a very big stack in which I had an S3 bucket and a trigger for every object that comes into that S3 bucket set to a lambda function.

I was doing that with this:

```
const myBucket= new Bucket(this, "somename", {
    encryption: BucketEncryption.KMS_MANAGED,
    bucketName: cfg.BUCKET_NAME_BACKEND,
    serverAccessLogsBucket: "some_logging_bucket",
    blockPublicAccess: BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
    versioned: true,
});

// Let's assume for simplicity that the lambda exists

myLambda.addEventSource(
    new S3EventSource(myBucket, {
        events: [EventType.OBJECT_CREATED],
    })
);
```

So essentialy creating a bucket, then adding a trigger for every new object that gets created to `myLambda`. And it was working just fine.

Now, in the new setup, my bucket is in `stack1` and the lambda is in `stack2` let's say.

Now I am doing something like this:

```
const myBucket = Bucket.fromBucketArn(this, "bucketBackend", "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket");

// Let's assume for simplicity that the lambda exists

myLambda.addEventSource(
    new S3EventSourceV2(myBucket, {
        events: [EventType.OBJECT_CREATED],
    })
);
```

But this unfortunately simply does not work.
There is no error, but the trigger does not get added.

There does not seem to be any difference between [V2 version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_event_sources.S3EventSourceV2.html) and [V1 version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_event_sources.S3EventSource.html) besides the fact that one of them wants a `Bucket` and the other one wants an `IBucket` which is exactly what I am doing. So far I am at a loss as to why this is not properly working, any ideas?

Edit 1: I am now thinking that maybe because I am trying to add a trigger to a bucket in `stack1` from `stack2`, maybe because the s3 bucket is a child of the `stack1` then I cannot modify it from another stack? Investigating.